# "error: cannot find -lGL" in Qt creator 5.5.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt, qt, qt5

I am trying to build and run a sample program on Qt creator 5.5.0 and Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS.

Every time its giving an error `cannot find -lGL and id returns exit 0`.

I tried to resolve this issue by installing  the GL libraries but when I run `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev` I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libglu1-mesa-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libglu1-mesa-dev' has no installation candidate
```

i have also tried other commands like

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`. and many others.

output of of cat `/etc/apt/sources.list` is

```
root@user-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/home/user# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src  us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe multiverse main restricted
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe multiverse main restricted #Added by software-properties
deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe multiverse main restricted
deb-src us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe multiverse main restricted #Added by software-properties
deb  security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe multiverse main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe multiverse main restricted #Added by software-properties
deb /us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports multiverse main universe restricted
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. The Package is in the main repository, eg `deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might run `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev` before running `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y`

Good luck :D